# Border-radius and greyscale filter cannot work together

Tags: html, css, filter, grayscale

I'm facing a problem with border-radius and greyscale filter. When I use them together, greyscale filter overlaps border-radius.

```
.sectionBlock#personal .photo{ perspective: 1px; border-radius: 100%; overflow: hidden; height: 300px; -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */filter: grayscale(100%);  }
.sectionBlock#personal .photo:hover{ -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */filter: grayscale(0%);}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Unable to replicate - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xEGaqW

Comment: It was working completely ok on firefox , so I used clip-path for chrome....